# Directory Common to all windows users

Tags: windows

I want to know the directory path that will be accessible by all user in windows.

Multiple user can share the file using that directory.

Comment: You should add more tags, is this a batch file or a win32 program?

Answer (score 1):

`%PUBLIC%` environment variable (it resolves to `C:\Users\Public` on my system).

Comment: Is this only available in windows 7. How to achieve the same in windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

To get the public folder (`FOLDERID_Public`) you should call [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

On < Vista you should probably use `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` or `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`...